# Abbrev proxy candidates in emacs icicles

Tags: emacs, icicles

I'm trying to use [`icicle-command-abbrev`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Multi_M-x#icicle-command-abbrev) to reduce the amount of typing that I do. I have proxy candidates enabled `(setq icicle-add-proxy-candidates-flag t)`,  (I can also enable them with `C-M-_` but, for some reason, I can never get `ff` to match `find-file`. Sorting is set to proxy coandidates first, and I have proxy candidates with a higher precedence than regular commands. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really say what behavior you see, corresponding to "*I can never get* `ff` *to match find-file.*"  Let me tell you what behavior you *should* see, and then you can please tell me what the difference is.

From your description, you should see proxy candidates in `*Completions*`.  When you use `icicle-command-abbrev` (bound to `C-x SPC` by default) and then you type `ff TAB` at the `M-x` prompt, you should see command names that have at least two parts that start with `f`, and you should see the proxy candidate `ff`, which should be highlighted (with face `icicle-proxy-candidate`). That proxy candidate should be the first candidate listed in `*Completions*` (because you have sorted proxy candidates first).

If you then cycle to that candidate (just hit `TAB` a second time, or the down arrow once), and then hit `RET` to choose it, the prompt should change to `Command abbreviated`ff`:`.  If you then hit `TAB` you should see in `*Completions*` the list of commands whose names have at least two parts that start with `f`.  You can then cycle to one or type more text to complete to one, to choose it.

*Let me know which part of this description you do not see.*

However, I just realized that there was a bug (a missing variable binding), which I have now fixed.  The symptom would be that when you choose command `find-file` a missing-variable-binding error was raised.  Please download the latest [`icicles-cmd1.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/icicles-cmd1.el), which has the fix.  (Or wait until the file is mirrored on [MELPA](http://melpa.milkbox.net/#/icicles), which could take up to a day.)

If what you see other than that bug is what I described, then you should be OK with the new version.  If not, please describe what you see that is different from my description.  Sorry for your trouble.

(You can of course just hit `RET` as soon as you type `ff`, to get the second completion prompt directly.  But first check that the recipe above works for you.)

Comment: My current symptoms are as follows: Only commands with the substring "ff" show up (things like ffip,ffap, etc.), that is all. There are no specially highlighted candidates and there is no `ff` proxy candidate. Pressing `RET` executes the first completion in the `*Completions*` buffer.

Comment: Also, do you use emacswiki as your repository? Do you have a bugtracker? I'd rather file bugs there (in the future) if it exists rather than here.

Comment: (1) I upload to EmacsWiki. That gets mirrored on MELPA. (2) The best way to file a bug for my Emacs libraries is to send me an email.  For **Icicles**, just `M-x icicle-send-bug-report`.

Comment: I don't recognize those symptoms at all. Are you sure that you invoked `icicle-command-abbrev` and not just `M-x` (i.e., `icicle-execute-extended-command`)? To be sure, try `M-x debug-on-entry RET icicle-command-abbrev`, and see if the debugger opens for it. Anyway, please follow up with me by email (check the file header). Try to give me a step-by-step recipe, starting from `emacs -Q` (e.g., mentioning any customizations needed to reproduce the problem).

Comment: You did, by mail, and I replied. There was a bug; should be OK now. Thx.